# Phonegap -how to use plugins when building locally

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, command-line-interface, local, phonegap-build

I am using the latest version of Phonegap and I am trying to include some plugins in my application. I have installed the plugins via cli and they appear in my plugins folder. However, even after referencing them in the config.xml I cannot get them to work. I have successfully used plugins via the phonegap online compiler but I do not know how to use them locally. Please help!

**FIXED** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

It turns out that I had everything correct in my project except for the cordova.js reference. I was physically referencing a copy that I had place in my js folder instead of only referencing it and allowing phonegap to generate the copy. The problem was in the fact that I then referenced js/cordova.js instead of cordova.js. Thanks for all of the suggestions below!

Comment: They only work on the phone. Are you testing in a browser?

Comment: No, I am testing on the simulator and on the iPhone itself.

Comment: You don't need to reference them in the config if you are building locally. That's only needed in Build. Which ones are you using?

Comment: I am using the dialogs plugin but I cannot get it to work for anything. I have installed the plugin via CLI and referenced it in my javascript. Is there anything else that I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

@Matt Butler, What do you mean you *cannot get them to work*? Can you get an APK? Will the install? Does the javascript work? Can you build Hello World?

Comment: The app runs just fine with the javascript and styling of the css. The only problem is that the plugins don't seem to exist or be active. What is the process of using a plugin for a local build?

Comment: Okay. I use PhoneGap Build, not the CLI (local build). I have [14 working examples for the core APIs] (http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html). If this does not help, you will need to be specific with one of the APIs and the code/build that does not work. This [reference for the CLI] (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) should help. **NOTE**: you tagged your post with phonegap-build, which is the cloud compiler/builder, not the CLI.